# radial gradient not working as expected

Tags: materials

So I was trying to apply a "radial" gradient on an object's front but for some reason it seems like the gradient got "stretched" and the gradient spanned across the objects and not just on a single object.

[image]

If you look at the screenshot, the left circle and the 2 small circles are both using the same material. The left one kinda looks about the same as what I had on the ColorRamp. But as you can see on the 2 small ones, the gradient spanned across the objects which isn't what I really wanted. The material is on the bottom

Comment: please provide blend file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you did mirror your object(circle) on the x-Axis.

Therefore you moved the vertices on the x-Axis while your origin of the object is still in the world center.

so you get this:

[image]

you will get this, if you move slightly the x slider to the right (hold Shift while dragging)

[image]

to "solve" your problem, you can:

1. apply the mirror modifier
2. select the small circle and press tab
3. separate by loose parts

[image]

4. tab -> object mode
5. select each circle and set origin -> to geometry
6. set the x value in the shader back to 0
7. and you get:

[image]

[image]

Comment: And if you don't want to apply the mirror, you could use the UV coordinate space (but then shift it by `0.5` on both axes).

Comment: This approach worked for me. Shame that I have to apply the mirror, I'll just repeat the steps when needed. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

When using Object coordinates the gradient will be centred on the origin of the object. Check the position of the origin of each of the objects to ensure it is centred within the geometry. If not, re-position the origin (there is a function to set origin to (centre of) geometry).

Comment: oh, I'll try that

Comment: It seems like it still didn't work

Comment: Please provide more info. In what way didn’t it work? Did it change anything? If so, what changed. It’s difficult to diagnose without more info. If all else fails, can you share your .blend file?